# Remove Sentence that Wraps an Element

Tags: javascript, adblock

I have a paragraph that has an anchor inside it that is blocked by AdBlock as it should be since it has ad served content. The problem is that it is in sentence that now no longer makes sense. I want to remove from period to period before and after the element. I am thinking some sort of regular expression, but do not have any clue of the pattern. Oh, and NO JQUERY PLEASE! Here is an example for reference:

```html
<div class="content">Ancient alien Annunaki otherworldly visitors clearly extraterrestrial golden disk mercury weightless, pre-colonial aerodynamics NASA clearly Vymaanika-Shaastra Sumerian texts space time. Burmuta triangle Indian texts clearly evidence cover up grey ancient alien, petroglyph sightings vimana Easter island gods inter-dimensional earth mound, I know it sounds crazy... Puma Punku mainstream archaelogy sightings.. Visit <a id="adContainer" href="https://ad.click.stuff">www.somesponsor.com</a> for details.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, all you need to do is ensure that the sentence is recognized as being part of the ad. For instance, you could add the class "ad-context" to the DIV element (as listed [in EasyList](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/blob/master/easylist/easylist_general_hide.txt)).

Comment: I have no control over the content, so I can only use javascript.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to modify the content but if that's not something that works in your case, you could wait for Adblock Plus to [implement the ability to hide parent elements](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/3143) and then ask [EasyList](http://easylist.github.io/) to add such a filter.